# What am I missing in my compilation / linking stage of this C++ FreeType GLFW application?

Tags: c++, freetype, glfw

```
g++ -framework OpenGL GLFT_Font.cpp test.cpp -o test -Wall -pedantic -lglfw  -lfreetype -    pthread `freetype-config --cflags`
Undefined symbols:
  "_GetEventKind", referenced from:
      __glfwKeyEventHandler in libglfw.a(macosx_window.o)
      __glfwMouseEventHandler in libglfw.a(macosx_window.o)
      __glfwWindowEventHandler in libglfw.a(macosx_window.o)
  "_ShowWindow", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformOpenWindow in libglfw.a(macosx_window.o)
  "_MenuSelect", referenced from:
```

This is on Mac OS X.

I am trying to get GLFT_FONT to work on MacOSX with GLFW and FreeType2. This is not the standard Makefile. I changed parts of it myself (like the "-framework OpenGL"

I am from Linux land, a bit new to Mac.

I am on Mac OS X 10.5.8; using XCode 3.1.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tink those come from the Carbon framework.

> LIBS += -framework Carbon

should do it then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link against the Carbon and AGL frameworks as well, i.e.

```
-framework AGL -framework Carbon
```

Also note that GLFW 2.6 only works as 32-bit on Mac OS X.